# how to update libc6 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, glibc

I am running into following error while compiling a build and based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found I tried to upgrade the libc using yum, brew,apt-get,none of them worked for me..what can I do?how can I upgrade libc6?

`arm-none-eabi-gcc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14 not found (required by arm-none-eabi-gcc)`

```
1.
[username@machine build]$ sudo yum install libc6
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package libc6 available.
Error: Nothing to do


2.
sudo brew install libc6
sudo: brew: command not found

3.
[username@machine build]$ sudo apt-get install libc6
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

UPDATE:-

```
[username@machinelinux8 build]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

[username@machinelinux8 build]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: OracleServer
Description:    Oracle Linux Server release 6.6
Release:    6.6
Codename:   n/a

[username@machinelinux8 build]$ uname -a
Linux machinelinux8 3.8.13-44.1.1.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Wed Sep 10 06:10:25 PDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[username@machinelinux8 build]$ cat /proc/cmdline 
ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_machinelinux8-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_machinelinux8/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_machinelinux8/lv_swap rd_NO_MD noapic crashkernel=257M@0M SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
```

Comment: Is the version of `arm-none-eabi-gcc` supported on Centos 6?  If it's a newer version, it may not be, and trying to update `libc` on a Centos 6-based distribution probably won't be sufficient.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Before that how do we even update ,I have tried different ways and none works for me

Comment: Have you checked `sudo yum update glibc` or see what versions maybe out there and install the specific one you need with `yum`? Simple enough to try I suppose.

Comment: Running that command gives me `Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Update Process

No Packages marked for Update`

Comment: @redl56789 [The last version of `arm-none-eabi-gcc` to support Centos 6 was 5-2016-q3-update.](https://community.arm.com/tools/f/discussions/8869/issue-arm-none-eabi-gcc-of-gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update-need-glibc_2-14-and-glibc_2-11) If your version is later than that, you pretty much **can't** run it on Centos 6.  And to be honest, if you have to *ask* how to update `libc`, you have no business even trying.  Pretty much the entire system is dependent upon `libc`, so changing it to a version the system wasn't built on top of is very likely to break your system.